# Create a copy of a table within the same database DB2

Tags: copy, db2, aix

Is there an easy way to copy a table to the same database of course with different name.
I tried some of these listed below,

`db2 "CREATE TABLE SCHEMA.NEW_TB COPY AS SELECT * FROM  SCHEMA.OLD_TB WHERE 1 = 2"`

`db2 "SELECT INTO SCHEMA.NEW_TB FROM SCHEMA.OLD_TB"`

`db2 "SELECT * FROM SCHEMA.OLD_TB INSERT INTO SCHEMA.NEW_TB"`

None of these worked 
I am using db2 v9.5

Comment: Why are You using 1 = 2 condition for this?

Comment: Oh, ok, because You don't want to copy data, just schema. Sorry for bothering You ;)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You have to surround the select part with parenthesis.

```
CREATE TABLE SCHEMA.NEW_TB AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM SCHEMA.OLD_TB
) WITH NO DATA
```

Should work.  Pay attention to all the things @Gilbert said would not be copied.

I'm assuming DB2 on Linux/Unix/Windows here, since you say DB2 v9.5.

Comment: Your `WHERE` condition is a little odd.  If you're using the false predicate to have DB2 not copy data, you can do it as I have here with `WITH NO DATA` to only copy the structure.  Or you can just do a `CREATE TABLE SCHEMA.NEW_TB LIKE SCHEMA.OLD_TB`.

Comment: Why "WITH NO DATA" Didn't he wanted to copy  the content too? How to create the table AND do inserts?

Comment: @ThorstenNiehues As much as it makes no sense why, there is no `WITH DATA` or `WITH ALL DATA` option, and you also cannot leave out the `WITH` clause. So we have to use `WITH NO DATA` (or the `LIKE` version) and then pump in the data using a separate `INSERT ... SELECT` query.

Answer (score 45):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE SCHEMA.NEW_TB LIKE SCHEMA.OLD_TB;
INSERT INTO SCHEMA.NEW_TB (SELECT * FROM SCHEMA.OLD_TB);
```

Options that are not copied include:

- Check constraints
- Column default values
- Column comments
- Foreign keys
- Logged and compact option on BLOB columns
- Distinct types

Comment: INSERT INTO SCHEMA.NEW_TB(column names) SELECT column,names FROM SCHEMA.OLD_TB;    some table had issues with column names not in the correct place and this helped to solve that issue.

Comment: This doesn't copy primary keys and indexs. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

```
CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLENAME LIKE OLD_TABLENAME;
```

Works for DB2 V 9.7

Comment: It DOES NOT copy DATA.

Comment: The question is actually not clear with regard to this requirement. The accepted answer does not copy data either.

Answer (score 4):

Two steps works fine:

```
create table bu_x as 
(select a,b,c,d from x ) 
WITH no data;

insert into bu_x  (a,b,c,d) select a,b,c,d from x ;
```

Comment: Can you confirm that `select select` in the second step is correct and intended?

Comment: `INSERT INTO XXX.YYY  (SELECT * FROM ZZZ.TTT)` worked for me on DB2 7

Answer (score 1):

```sql
CREATE TABLE SCHEMA.NEW_TB COPY AS 
(SELECT * FROM  SCHEMA.OLD_TB WHERE 1 = 2)
WITH DATA
```

Works for me all the time

Comment: `WHERE 1 = 2` and `WITH DATA` cancel each other out, being the same as a query without the `WHERE` clause but with `WITH NO DATA`.

Answer (score 0):

We can copy all columns from one table to another, existing table:

INSERT INTO table2
 SELECT * FROM table1;

Or we can copy only the columns we want to into another, existing table:

INSERT INTO table2
 (column_name(s))
 SELECT column_name(s)
 FROM table1;

or SELECT * INTO BACKUP_TABLE1 FROM TABLE1